# Trying To Get Max Number In A Range

Tags: excel, vba

**Hi,** I am trying to get the max number from a range. I have tied **2 approaches to do this**, one is working other is not but it should work. Below code is working for me, I can get max with this code.

```
Dim mymax As Range
    Set mymax = Range("b13").CurrentRegion
    Range("b11").Value = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(mymax)
```

Now the code below this is not working, why it is not working? Technically it should work. Can you please let me why its not giving me max number?

```
Dim mymax As String
       mymax = Range("b13").CurrentRegion.Address
       Range("b11").Value = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(mymax)
```

Thanks for your time and opinion.

Comment: Just have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.max): _Arguments that are error values or text that cannot be translated into numbers cause errors._

Comment: Have read the documentation. So we need to feed number, name, array or references. What I dont get is .address returns reference address say "A1:C30", yes the data type is string.      If we use =max(address) in excel sheet it gives max value. Above code returns "Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(A1:C3) so should it not be working here. Thats what I don't understand.

Comment: And the address (A1:C30) returned by variable mymax contains numbers

Comment: In VBA A1:C3 is not defined, only `"A1:C3"` is considered as a string and in the excel sheet A1:C3 is a range. To make it clearer if you enter in your sheet the formula `=MAX("A1:C3")` you will get an error.

Comment: @Storax I understand it now. And -FaneDuru's code makes it very clear. Using "Range" with max makes it work >> Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(mymax))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you tried in the second code will work only in the next two ways:

```
Dim mymax As String
    mymax = Range("b13").CurrentRegion.Address
    Range("b11").Value = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(mymax))
```

You must (re)transform the string in a range...

```
Dim myArr As Variant
    myArr = Range("b13").CurrentRegion.Value
    Range("C11").Value = Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(myArr)
```

`Max` function works for arrays, too...

Comment: @Ali Zubair: Should I understand that my code answers your question? If yes, glad I could help! In such a case, we here tick the code left side check box in order to make it **accepted answer"". In such a case, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the answer was appropriate...

Comment: Yes it also works. I have tried the one that converts string to range. Now it makes sense, everything we do with cells or ranges in vba we use range to declare its a range so using it here makes sense. Will try the 2nd one also

Answer (score 0):

"Technically it should work"?  What gives you that idea?  You are passing a string to a function expecting a range - there is no "technically", it simply doesn't work as you are using a wrong variable type.

There is a reason the first example works.  In VBA you `set` ranges and that's what in does.

In the second example you are using a string when a function is expecting a range which simply cannot work.  The `Max` function on the spreadsheet would not work with a string input - there is no reason why it should this way in VBA.

Let me put this this way:

[image]

Your second code was the equivalent of formula in E1, which returns 0.  What you are looking for, was the formula in E2, which returns 4.

Comment: The function is not expecting a range, I'd recommend to look at the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.max). A call like `WorksheetFunction.Max(rg1,12,25,rg2)` would be valid. Even a call with a string would be valid in case the string converts into a number.

Comment: I was saying technically becuase variable mymax returns reference address "A1:C30", and this address contains numbers so it should work. In excel we say =max(A1:C30) right, After running the code it becomes Excel.Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(A1:C30) so shouldn't it work?

Comment: @AliZubair - there is a difference between returning a string which reads "A1:C30" or a range referring to "A1:C30".  Please see my edited answer.